# In a MongoDB query, what does a negative limit mean?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm using the Mongoid ruby gem to interact w/ MongoDB and when I try to get one of something from a query, it adds `$limit: -1` (i.e. negative one) when I would expect it to just use `1`. I tried doing the same thing in the console and it didn't change which document was returned.

Does a negative limit mean something special?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a note on negative limits under the "numberToReturn" heading in the ["OP_QUERY" section of the "Mongo Wire Protocol" documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/#op-query).

> "If the client driver offers 'limit' functionality (like the SQL LIMIT
>   keyword), then it is up to the client driver to ensure that no more
>   than the specified number of document are returned to the calling
>   application. If numberToReturn is 0, the db will used the default
>   return size. If the number is negative, then the database will return
>   that number and close the cursor. No further results for that query
>   can be fetched."

For more information on cursors and limit, please see the ["Queries and Cursors" documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors), specifically the now-removed ["Execution of queries in batches"](http://web.archive.org/web/20120207133613/http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors#QueriesandCursors-Executionofqueriesinbatches) section.

Comment: *If the number is negative, then the database will return that number and close the cursor* - what an ugly hack!

Answer (score 5):

The sign of the limit value determines whether its a 'hard limit' or a 'soft limit'.  A 'hard limit' (negative sign) query closes the cursor after it has returned the maximum number of documents it can.  A 'soft limit' keeps the cursor open in case the response can not fit as many documents as specified by the limit.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this up? I haven't come across this before.

Comment: Also, is which is the soft limit-- positive or negative?

Comment: @nicholaides: I've added a [link to the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/#op-query) in [Marc's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9845613/1269037).